# How to open embedded resource word document?

Tags: c#, ms-word, embedded-resource

I have a embedded word template document in my project, I added it as resource (Resources.resx -> Add resource -> Add existing file) and now I want to open it something like this

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Document document = application.Documents.Open(Properties.Resources.MyDoc);
```

But unfortunately the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application doesn't work with byte arrays and I can't set MyDoc to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word can only open files that exist in the filesystem, it cannot work entirely from-memory.

Do something like this:

```
String fileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
File.WriteAllBytes( fileName , Properties.Resources.MyDoc );
application.Documents.Open( fileName  );
```

Then when you've detected Word has been closed, delete the file:

```
File.Delete( fileName );
```

It might be an idea (for performance reasons) to embed the Word document as an Embedded Resource instead of a `Byte[]` array within a `resx` file, like so:

```
Assembly thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
System.IO.Stream resourceStream = thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream("MyDoc.docx");
// copy the stream to a new FileStream, then open Word as-before
```