# Programmatically Open Word Document Located in the Resource1.resx in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

Im using WinForms and i try to open MS Word document (with some help info) on button click from my form

My code :

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application ap = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Document document = ap.Documents.Open(Resource1.sign_full);
```

My .docx file is sign_full.docx. I added it to my project Resource1.resx file.
Then If I press button1  i get

> Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH)) error in "ap.Documents.Open(Resource1.sign_full)" line

Is there any way to open it using Documents.Open? Or shoud i use somthing else?

Comment: The `Open` method requires a file name. You could store the resource to a temporary file and then provide that path to the `Open` method.

Comment: Also, not sure if it makes difference but did you try adding the file extension? (Resource1.sign_full.docx)

Comment: Adam McMahon, i tried but that make no difference

Answer (score 2):

The answer could be found here: [How to open embedded resource word document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164270/how-to-open-embedded-resource-word-document)

Word can only open files that exist in the filesystem, it cannot work entirely from-memory.
Do something like this:

```
String fileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
File.WriteAllBytes( fileName , Properties.Resources.sign_full.docx);
application.Documents.Open(fileName);
```

Then when you've detected Word has been closed, delete the file:

```
File.Delete( fileName );
```

Comment: can i delete file while word is still opened?

Comment: like insert word document in memory with this hack and forget about it

Comment: it's mentioned that you can't do that. after closing it out could delete it